# How do you handle / manipulate split images

Tags: html, image, user-interface, split

We have a requirement to display short / bigger size images. (e.g. I could have the front portion of the bus, back portion of the bus and middle portion of the bus as separate images).

So to demonstrate the above, I could try

```
front,middle,middle,back (to construct shorter image)
front,middle,middle,middle,middle,back (to construct bigger image)
```

Are there any sites which let you download such images (i.e. they are already split) OR what would be an easier way to achieve this from an already available image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick. Check the [following example](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.com/2010/02/imagemagick-split-one-image-to-smaller.html).

In your case if  you want to split image only horizontally in (let's assume) 200px slices:

```
convert -crop 200 +repage verybig.jpg slice%02d.jpg
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to copy the external files from an external site, but are there ways to split any image (e.g. a image provided by us) using an image manipulation tool.

Comment: I modified my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could slice and dice an existing image with HTML/CSS, by setting up several adjacent elements with the same image as a background, then manipulating the widths and background position to get the desired effect.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gjJcM/

You'd need to know something about the image content you're working with to make this seamless - I'd need more context to think in further detail.

HTH

Comment: i would not suggest using peter's solution, as it is not optimal. his idea requires the entire image to be loaded for every CSS div/span/etc, which increases load time significantly as opposed to loading smaller, "sized" images. it's about the same as resizing a 1000x1000 image to 10x10 using CSS and calling it a thumbnail, even though it has a small display, the user still has to download the entire full-size file.

Comment: Peter's response is a valid solution.  It is the same as using CSS sprites in HTML5.  The server is only hit once for the large file and then the file is manipulated in the browser.

Comment: The cost/benefit would depend on the particulars of the base image size and how much of it ends up being displayed in the various HTML elements that use it as a background (not enough detail in the question to know).

Answer (score 2):

The slicing and dicing can also be done with the [Gimp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP).

Check out the Gimp's Filters->Map->Make-Seamless.  It's used to make tiles join up seamlessly both horizontally and vertically.  You can use it to make a horizontally repeatable tile by adding extra background above and below, and then after use cropping away the excess.

A more sophisticated tool for making the seamless join is [panotools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/).

Combining the pieces at the end is easiest if you include half of the middle of the bus with the back and half of the middle with the front.  You won't get a bus with no middle, but from the question, that's not something you needed.